# regex registry replace

Tags: regex, windows, registry, notepad++

I have bunch of windows registry .reg files and would like to make some changes into them, replacing SID with HKCU.

files look like this:

```
[-HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-**********-********-*********-500\SomeKey\SomeSubKey]
blah blah blah
[-HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-**********-********-*********-500_Classes\SomeKey\SomeSubKey]
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-**********-********-*********-500\SomeKey\SomeSubKey]
blah blah blah
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-**********-********-*********-500_Classes\SomeKey\SomeSubKey]
```

and the expected result would be like this:

```
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SomeKey\SomeSubKey]
blah blah blah
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\SomeKey\SomeSubKey]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SomeKey\SomeSubKey]
blah blah blah
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\SomeKey\SomeSubKey]
```

I basically know what should be done but as regex is not my language maybe someone will help me :)

The idea is to search at the beginning of the line for `[HKEY` or `[-HKEY`
continue until `*-500`
replace `HKEY* until *-500` with `HKEY\`.
Of course there is 500 vs 500_Classes and Software thing, but if given right direction I could figure out that myself or do a double run.
I would use Notepad++ for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find

```
\[(-)?HKEY_USERS\\S-1-5-21-.{10}-.{8}-.{9}-500(_Classes)?(.*)
```

and replace with

```
[$1HKEY_CURRENT_USER(?{2}\\Software\\Classes)$3
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me good visual representation how it works.